# How to install .inf file in windows 7 using cmd

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, drivers, batch

Hello i had installed windows 7 on my Dell Latitude E6410. I am using [Driver Easy](https://www.drivereasy.com/download-free-version/) to download missing drivers. All drivers I have downloaded but they are in .inf file. I have used device manager to install some of them by right clicking on the driver and by browsing it manually. Some of them I don't know for which category they are. I want to install these software form CMD. I had visited this link [Installing a .inf file using a windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619604/installing-a-inf-file-using-a-windows-batch-file) but not helpful, I had used `pnputil -i -a <inffilename>` and I had also tried command `RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 path-to-inf\infname.inf` from Microsoft Docs [Command-Line or Batch File Install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/using-an-inf-file-to-install-a-file-system-filter-driver). The issue when I press enter after typing command with path and file name there's nothing happen no prompt displayed for installation completed or not installed it's nothing happen when I press enter. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To install a inf file:

regsvr32 Filename.inf

To uninstall

regsvr32 /u Filename.inf

To install all inf file in a folder from the command line:

for %a in (*.inf) do regsvr32 "%a"

Comment: what is %a in the syntax?

Comment: The replacement variable for each *.inf file that exist in the folder where you run the comand. It could be any letter doesn't have necessarily be a....

Comment: shouldn't the last one require *'setlocal enableDelayExpansion'*?

Comment: No not necessary

Comment: is regsvr32 really appropriate for *.inf? MS documentation only mentions *.dll 's